# Drawing alphabet E in ios

Tags: ios, calayer, bezier, quartz-core

How to draw an alphabet E in ios using *beizer* path or something?

I tried with normal image for E but its varying according to screen resolution but it should not vary,so I am going to draw via coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom view. (subclass of `UIView)`. And change its draw rect method like this.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     [super drawRect:rect];

     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

     CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);

     CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0,0);

     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, 60);

     CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0,0);

     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 30, 0);

     CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 30);

     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, 30);

     CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 60);

     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 30, 60);

     CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

you can change line color, width or any other properties as you want.

**Edit:**
For center,

First define width of E character, let say;

```
#define VERTICAL_LINE 40
#define TOP_HORIZONTAL_LINE 40
#define CENTER_HORIZONTAL_LINE 40
#define BOTTOM_HORIZONTAL_LINE 40
#define LINE_PIECE 20
```

And drawRect method;

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);


    // assumed top and bottom lines are equal width

    CGFloat x, y;
    x = (self.frame.size.width - MAX(TOP_HORIZONTAL_LINE,CENTER_HORIZONTAL_LINE)) / 2;
    y = (self.frame.size.height - VERTICAL_LINE) / 2;

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, y + VERTICAL_LINE);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x,y);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x+TOP_HORIZONTAL_LINE, y);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y+LINE_PIECE);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x+CENTER_HORIZONTAL_LINE, y+LINE_PIECE);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y+VERTICAL_LINE);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x + BOTTOM_HORIZONTAL_LINE, y + VERTICAL_LINE);

    // and now draw the Path!
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: :Thanks.It's working :) fine.But how to make it to the center of the view  ?

Comment: working like a charm!!!

Comment: @calgar:i need the center horizontal line of the E also same length,but if i increase the length in #define CENTER_HORIZONTAL_LINE 40 means,that line is not visible..can u please help me to fix this

Comment: I tried again with (VERTICAL_LINE 80,TOP_HORIZONTAL_LINE 40, CENTER_HORIZONTAL_LINE 40,BOTTOM_HORIZONTAL_LINE 40 ) these values, but your situation did not appear.I mean it is working. Are there any changes you made?

Comment: @calgar:No,i didn't made any change.i need all the lines in same size.

Comment: @Calgar:And by the way background  looks dark, i'm trying to change but not changing.

Comment: For same size issue, I edited the answer.

Comment: @calgar:Thanks alot:) can i have your mail id.i like to keep in touch with you ?

Comment: @calgar:how to make the width and height as 5.62mm of this E?

Comment: @calgar:Expecting your reply

Comment: I am not an expert for this. I am sorry , I really do not know how to make 5.62mm. Asking another question in different topic may help. I am sure someone know.

Comment: Do you how to find the x y position in xib